# Trying to rewrite App.js as a class

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to re-write the entry point App.js javascript file as a class.  I'm doing this because I want to call an onClick function when a user clicks on the log out link.

Here is the current code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { IndexLink, Link } from 'react-router';

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <IndexLink className="mypad" to="home">Home</IndexLink>
            <Link className="mypad" to="">Log Out</Link>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};

App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element
};

export default App;
```

Here was my attempt at re-writing this as a class.  It doesn't work.  I get the error:  'ReferenceError: props is not defined'

```
class App extends React.Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <IndexLink className="mypad" to="home">Home</IndexLink>
                <Link className="mypad" to="">Log Out</Link>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `this.props` once its a class

```
  <div>
    <IndexLink className="mypad" to="home">Home</IndexLink>
    <Link className="mypad" to="">Log Out</Link>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
```

when you write the component as a function, props gets passed in as an argument. When you do it as a class, props are bound to the instance of the component object.

Answer (score 0):

add this => `this.props.children`